# Plotting large number of time series using ggplot. Is it possible to speed up?

Tags: r, performance, ggplot2, plot, time-series

I am working with thousands of meteorological time series data (Sample data can be downloaded from here)
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bxioonfzqa4np6y/timeSeries.txt

Plotting these data using ggplot2 on my Linux Mint PC (64bit, 8GB RAM, Dual-core 2.6 GHz) took a lot of time. I'm wondering if there is a way to speed it up or a better way to plot these data? Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion!

This is the code I'm using for now

```
##############################################################################
#### load required libraries
library(RCurl)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

##############################################################################
#### Read data from URL
dataURL <- "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bxioonfzqa4np6y/timeSeries.txt"
tmp <- getURL(dataURL)
df <- tbl_df(read.table(text = tmp, header = TRUE))
df

##############################################################################
#### Plot time series using ggplot2
# Melt the data by date first
df_melt <- melt(df, id = "date")
str(df_melt)

df_plot <- ggplot(data = df_melt, aes(x = date, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_discrete("Station #") +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Daily Precipitation [mm]") +
  ggtitle("Daily precipitation from 1915 to 2011") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold", vjust = 2)) + # Change size & distance of the title
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, size = 12, vjust = 0.5)) + # Change size of tick text
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, size = 12, vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme( # Move x- & y-axis lables away from the axises
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", vjust = -0.35),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", vjust = 0.35)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(colour = "chocolate", size = 14, face = "bold")) + # Change Legend text size
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4))) + # Change legend symbol size
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncols = 2))
df_plot
```

Comment: Please do not post lines that destroy readers' workspace.

Comment: As you want to render a point each day on the `x` axis for around 100 years, this means that a minimum ~35K width is required for your plot -- if you want to show 1 pixel large points. I doubt it's really needed, why not aggregate then?

Comment: @daroczig ...or buy 15 monitors to display it on. :)

Comment: ggplot2 is not optimized for handling large data, rather it's optimized for programmer convenience.  You will find that base plot or lattice are 100s of times faster.  For ggplot2 you might consider reducing the data size first, for example by subsampling or aggregating.

Comment: +1 for providing your data, and for a working code example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion everyone! The reason I want to plot all the stations as time series in the same plot is to have an overview of how the data look like e.g. any errors/abnormal values etc. I totally agree that it makes much more sense to aggregate the date into monthly, seasonal & annual data. I didn't know that lattice can deal with this better than ggplot2

Comment: what about the latest ggplot2 versions?. Are they faster?.  I'm looking forward to seeing vispy integrated with R

Comment: @skan: unfortunately it's still very slow after almost 4 years

Comment: @skan: quick update: using [R 4.0.0](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2020/04/r-400-is-released.html) and [the new implementation of grid units](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/04/13/changes-to-grid-units/), it's about 25% faster generating the plot in the example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Part of your question asks for a "better way to plot these data".

In that spirit, you seem to have two problems, First, you expect to plot >35,000 points along the x-axis, which, as some of the comments point out, will result in pixel overlap on anything but an extremely large, high resolution monitor. Second, and more important IMO, you are trying to plot 69 time series (stations) on the same plot. In this type of situation a heatmap might be a better approach.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)          # for melt(...)
library(RColorBrewer)      # for brewer.pal(...)
url <-  "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bxioonfzqa4np6y/timeSeries.txt"
dt  <- fread(url)
dt[,Year:=year(as.Date(date))]

dt.melt  <- melt(dt[,-1,with=F],id="Year",variable.name="Station")
dt.agg   <- dt.melt[,list(y=sum(value)),by=list(Year,Station)]
dt.agg[,Station:=factor(Station,levels=rev(levels(Station)))]
ggplot(dt.agg,aes(x=Year,y=Station)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=y)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn("Annual\nPrecip. [mm]",
                       colours=rev(brewer.pal(9,"Spectral")))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Note the use of `data.tables`. Your dataset is fairly large (because of all the columns; 35,000 rows is not all that large). In this situation `data.tables` will speed up processing substantially, especially `fread(...)` which is much faster than the text import functions in base R.

Comment: Thanks @jlhoward for the idea & also the solution that used data.tables. I always want to try this package.