# How do I make a scatterplot in R with hundreds of y vairables?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

```
       head(data)
           Age   Vial.ID   X280.106.1  X324.106.1  X337.106.1  X337.106.2
        1  NA      NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
        2   2      NA         NA         NA       4.18       0.36
        3   3      NA         NA         NA       1.17       1.15
        4   4      NA         NA         NA       1.12       1.17
        5   5      NA         NA         NA       0.87       1.12
        6   6      NA         NA         NA       0.96       3.07
```

This is my data set. I have Age which ranges from 2-34 which I want on my x-axis. Then I have the vial numbers X`280.106.1, X324.106.1`... There are 447 vile numbers. I want to make a scatterplot where I have `age` on the x-axis and the number associated with the age on the y-axis. The only way I can seem to make one is

```
    plot(data$Age, data$X337.106.1)
    points(data$Age, data$X337.106.2)
    points(data$Age, data$X337.106.3)
    points(data$Age, data$X351.106.1)
```

This way works, but I would need to repeat the steps almost 500 times to get what I need. I know there are better ways, but I am not sure what they are. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Comment: @R.Gould: or you can convert your data from wide to long format and use `ggplot` for plotting. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25273358/ (`melt`) or https://stackoverflow.com/a/48871624/ (`gather`)

Comment: How could I get a trendline on here. Just for now a linear trendline? I was thinking or using lm(df[,1],df[,-1], data=data) but this doesn't work