# Type "h" plot gives me points instead of vertical lines (R)

Tags: r, plot

Hi my problem is that yesterday i created a plot of type "h" and it gave me a plot with vertical lines which is perfect to plot stock returns. Then today, i try to run it again and now the plot is giving me points instead of vertical lines... any idea?

I know it sounds a little weird but it's not the first time that i try to run code previously saved in R and that it doesn't work anymore! It's really frustrating but i guess that i'm probably missing something...

I tried to restart my computer and running the code again but it still the same and i tried changing type to "l" to see if it would work but i still get points instead of lines

## Code:

```
PSet1_W2019 <- read.table("PSet1_W2019.txt",header = TRUE, skipNul = T )
colnames(PSet1_W2019)[colnames(PSet1_W2019)=="ÿþ"] <- "...1"
PSet1_W2019$TSXr<- c(0, diff(PSet1_W2019$TSX)/PSet1_W2019$`TSX`[-length(PSet1_W2019$`TSX`)])

plot(PSet1_W2019$...1,PSet1_W2019$TSXr,xlab="Trading day", ylab="TSX returns", type = 'h')
legend("topright", legend=c("mean", "median","10e quantiles","25e quantiles","75e quantiles","90e quantiles"),
       col=c("red", "orange","darkblue","blue","magenta","darkmagenta"),lty = 1,cex = 0.7)
```

## Datas (PSet1_W2019)

Original datas- https://www.dropbox.com/s/aq7kga9m09du1kh/PSet1_W2019.txt?dl=0
dput(head(PSet1_W2019))-https://www.dropbox.com/s/4huw8ma3wvryh3v/dput%28%20%29.txt?dl=0

[Picture: What i get(without the horizontal lines though)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38B7M.png)

[image]

Comment: Please only include relevant code ie reduce your code to only that needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What is `PSet1_W2019$...1`?

Comment: Yeah i know i reduced it already and i should reduce even more but at the same time i really don't know the problem is coming from which part of the code so it's a little hard to know what to remove

Comment: It's the first column (the date)

Comment: They both give a very long result so i'm going to add : head(dput(PSet1_W2019)), which the same i think.

Comment: The right command is `dput(head(PSet1_W2019))`, not `head(dput(PSet1_W2019))`

Comment: I couldn't put it all so i inserted a part of the beginning and inserted a picture as well

Comment: @AudreyBeaudoin: sharing the output of `dput()` like that is not helpful. You can share the whole txt file via dropbox like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/25273358/786542

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tung for your help, i didn't know i could share datas that way. I think it's better now!